# NPM script to remove a string from file after processing?

Tags: javascript, node.js, string

In the `package.json` in my Angular 6 project, we have a bunch of node scripts to run and build our project.

I created a new script to process a scss file into an output directory:

```
 "unbranded": "node-sass -x --output-style expanded ./client/src/app/demo/unbrandeddemo/unbranded.scss > ./dspackage/dist/css/unbranded.css",
```

This creates a css file at `./dspackage/dist/css/unbranded.css`

Now I need to find and remove a string in this file after it's made.  So I created tried installing the `replace-in-file` npm package and am trying

```
"postunbranded": "replace-in-file from to ./dspackage/dist/css/unbranded.css, ./dspackage/dist/css/unbranded.css --configFile=replace-config.js"
```

Where the `replace-config-js` is a file in the same directory as the `package.json`,

```
const options = {
  from: /::ng-deep/g,
  to: ''
};
```

I've tried various versions of this setup, but get the error:

```
Error: must provide pattern
```